# Book recommendation: which ones should I study in order to learn information geometry, copulas and everything in between?

Tags: self-study, references, copula, information-geometry

So far I have been studying the theory of copulas for a while and I became fascinated by it. More recently, I read about information geometry which also caught my attention. Having said that, could someone suggest any material (mainly books) which would allow me to understand properly the subject.

Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: Could you tell us something about your background and goals? "everything in between" is rather broad ...